# Resizing kendo datepicker control's overall size

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I am using Kendo controls for styling my application, I was able to customize the css of almost all other kendo controls by overwriting default css but I am unable to do that in the case of Kendo datepicker.

I have tried many things but I am only able to change the font size inside the calendar/month view. but the height and width of the datepicker's selection box is too big and that doesn't look good in my page.

Can somebody help me to know how to resize the whole calendar container to be smaller that how it looks now.

I have added a live sample link and an image below for reference.

[image: Sample image]

Live sample - [click here for a live sample datepicker simulation](https://dojo.telerik.com/aGeNEWaf)

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to play around with the values to get it the exact size you want, but this should work:

```
.k-calendar-monthview .k-calendar-td,
.k-month-calendar .k-calendar-td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  inline-size: 20px;
  block-size: 20px;
}
.k-calendar .k-calendar-cell-inner,
.k-calendar .k-link {
  font-size: 8px;
}
.k-calendar-view {
  min-height: min-content;
  max-width: min-content;
}
.k-calendar-th {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 8px;
}
.k-button-md {
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fix. I was trying to reduce the padding inside the cell and having hard time finding a fix. 
This helped me a lot. I have applied similar customisation to year view and decade view so that the control will always be of the similar size.

Comment: Only thing that is still pending is, when I move to future months by clicking on the right arrow, it first moves from right to left and show the next month. During that month change, control gets bigger and then when the next month loads fully then it come back to its smaller size. 

Not sure whether this can be fixed as it is happening in an animated manner.

Comment: @Karthik You can fix that by adding this:

`.k-popup .k-calendar { max-width: 150px; }`

Comment: Thank you! your time on this was much appreciated.